# Open date strategy variable

Tags: date, pine-script

I'm trying to make a specific trail stop in my strategy script.

I want to make a for loop to evaluate all candles from open strategy date until today.

Is there a Pine Script variable which contains open position date or number of days or similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable that I know of that records the date of entries, but since it's your strategy, you should know when it's entering/exiting trades, so you should be able to save the `time` when those events occur.

Also, rather than waiting for a number of bars to elapse and go back over them with a `for` loop, it will be much more efficient for you to start tracking whatever info you need from the moment your condition triggers. For most needs, this should allow you to forego using a `for` loop.